# How to delete lowercase letters after the second upper case found in the line?

Tags: bash

I have a file with names:

```
Smith, John.
Brown, Aaron K.
```

And want to get:

```
Smith, J
Brown, A K
```

or better:

```
SmithJ
BrownAK
```

Can this task be solved in bash?

Comment: I would use `sed`: 
1. Put the line in hold space. 
2. Remove the first word from the line. 
3. Remove all except upper case character from the line. 
4. Switch hold space with pattern space. 
5. Extract the first word from the line. 
6. Append hold space to pattern space.

Comment: Thanks, of course that sed. I just don't know how to 'catch' the space between the first and third upper letters.

Comment: Don't catch it. That's why use hold space, to hold the first word. So you can just remove the first word, then remove all letter globally except upper letters. `s/[^ ]*//; s/[^A-Z]//g`. Reading the file line by line in shell and running two seds, first that extracts the first word and second that extracts the upper case letters, and then concatenating them in shell, it would be more comfortable to code for someone not proficient in `sed`. Anyway,Please post your attempt. What research did you make?What you have tried?How did you tried to solve the problem? It's really appreciated on this forum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve it with different tools and different methods. I will show two solutions using `sed` and one without.

## Solution 1

You want to use some command on part of the line.
You can remove all non-uppercase characters from a string with `echo "${string}" | tr -cd "[:upper:]"`.
With `sed s/../../e` the resulting line from the substitition is given to the shell.
Combining these give you:

```
sed -r 's/([^,]*)(.*)/echo "\1\$(echo "\2" | tr -cd "[:upper:]")"/e' file
```

## Solution 2

Less creative but easier to write is temporarily splitting each line in two lines, and execute the substition on the even lines. Put the lines together and your finished.

```
sed -e 's/,/\n/' file | sed '0~2s/[^A-Z]//g' | paste -d '' - -
```

## Solution 3

With the `tr` from the first and the `paste` from the second solution you can avoid `sed`.
Be aware that the `tr` characterset must include a newline.

```
paste -d '' <(cut -d, -f1 file) <(cut -d, -f2 file | tr -cd ':[A-Z]:\n')
```

IMHO the second solution looks best. The first one is slow on large files.